# How to make the result of the query to be selected on a dropdown menu

Tags: php, sql, drop-down-menu

I have this database:

```
  **SBU                **SBU_Users
 *id | *SBU_Name       *users_id | *sbu_id
  1  |  SBU1               1     |   3
     : 
  4  |  SBU4
```

And this my code:

```
$query = "SELECT sbu.SBU_Name, sbu_users.sbu_id FROM sbu, sbu_users WHERE sbu_users.sbu_id=sbu.id AND sbu_users.users_id=".$users_id."";
        $result = mysql_query($query, $db) or die (mysql_error($db));
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
            extract($row);

            }
            echo "<select name=sbuuser>";
            echo "<option value='1' ";if ($sbu_id==1){echo "selected";} else {echo "";}echo ">SBU1</option>";
            echo "<option value='2' ";if ($sbu_id==2){echo "selected";} else {echo "";}echo ">SBU2</option>";
            echo "<option value='3' ";if ($sbu_id==3){echo "selected";} else {echo "";}echo ">SBU3</option>";
            echo "<option value='4' ";if ($sbu_id==4){echo "selected";} else {echo "";}echo ">SBU4</option>";
```

I have a problem in selecting the right SBU_Name, because my code keeps selecting the last SBU_Name. Please help me.

Comment: You would have to put your echo statements inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
$query = "SELECT sbu.SBU_Name, sbu_users.sbu_id FROM sbu, sbu_users WHERE sbu_users.sbu_id=sbu.id AND sbu_users.users_id=".$users_id."";
        $result = mysql_query($query, $db) or die (mysql_error($db));

            echo "<select name=sbuuser>";

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
            extract($row);

            echo "<option value='1' ";if ($sbu_id==1){echo "selected";} else {echo "";}echo ">SBU1</option>";
            echo "<option value='2' ";if ($sbu_id==2){echo "selected";} else {echo "";}echo ">SBU2</option>";
            echo "<option value='3' ";if ($sbu_id==3){echo "selected";} else {echo "";}echo ">SBU3</option>";
            echo "<option value='4' ";if ($sbu_id==4){echo "selected";} else {echo "";}echo ">SBU4</option>";
            }

            echo "</select>";
```